# Junit test case :: external web-service calls

Tags: web-services, junit

I am trying to write a junit test case for my service layer class.

These methods in this service layer class has call to an external web-service which is deployed on a separate machine.

I want to make sure that the test methods are executed only when this external web-service is up and running.

Is there any convenient way to achieve this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would try to avoid referencing the web-service all together. In unit testing it's normally a good idea to avoid database references, web-service calls, http, etc. since they are

1. Slow
2. Not consistent (as you said, the web service may be down)
3. Not part of this "unit" - they should be tested separately

I'm not sure how your calls are being done, but look into mocking (with something like [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)). If you are able to mock the object that calls your web service, you can just tell it to return fake values (or do nothing), and then just verify that the web service was called. This way you are sure that *your* part of the code is working correctly, and as long as the web service is working correctly, then you should be good to go.

If you definitely need to access it, you can use try/catches to see if it times out, and only run the rest of the test if it doesn't do so. This way the catch will let the test pass without failing if the service is down.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. One question. If I opt for the try/catch approach is it possible to put the try/catch logic at a 'common' place? Meaning, lets say there are around 5 test methods in the test case, then instead of putting the try/catch in each of the method, I can have it in one place and ignore all 5 test methods if there is a request time-out [I/O exception]?

Comment: Yep! Use the @BeforeClass tag to run a method once before the entire class is run - here, do your try/catch. Create a global variable, say `isRunning`, and set it to either true/false in the try/catch, respectively. Then, in each test that you access the service, put in the line `assumeTrue(isRunning);`. This line will make sure that `isRunning` is true, and if not, it will skip the test completely! You will need to import org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue. That should solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks again. I am not using annotation based test cases. Is there an alternative for @BeforeClass annotation?

Comment: You could try setting up a main method, testing to see if it is running first, and  then call to perform the tests? I've never done that before, but it sounds like it could work. Some info [here](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/JUnit/Do_You_Need_to_Write_a_main_Method_in_a_JUnit_.html), not sure how accurate it is.